# Changing Div's based on dropdown and information in hash url

Tags: javascript, html, hash

Here is my code to change div based on selection from drop down menu:

```
<form name="AdditionalLayer" class="form" id="selectLayers">
    <select size="1">
    <option value="">Layer:</option>
    <option value="">-----------------------</option> 
    <option value="day1">Day 1</option>
    <option value="day2">Day 2</option>
    <option value="day3">Day 3</option>
    </select>
   </form>


<script>  document.getElementById("selectLayers").addEventListener('change', function handleChange(event) {
          if (event.target.value === 'day1') {
            document.getElementById("legend_day1").style.display = 'block';
          } else {
            document.getElementById("legend_day1").style.display = 'none'; {

              if (event.target.value === 'day2') {
                document.getElementById("legend_day2").style.display = 'block';
              } else {
                document.getElementById("legend_day2").style.display = 'none'; {
                  if (event.target.value === 'day3') {
                    document.getElementById("legend_day3").style.display = 'block';
                  } else {
                    document.getElementById("legend_day3").style.display = 'none';
                  }
                });
</script>


<div id="legend_day1">day 1 Legend</div>
<div id="legend_day2" style="display: none;">day 2 Legend</div>
<div id="legend_day3" style="display: none;">day 3 Legend</div>
```

My issue is how to get the correct div to show based on the hash url "#4/38.00/-97.03/day3". How would I be able to have day2 or day3 to display the correct div without having to reselect in the drop down? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*I have got this working with this code*" - given the syntax errors that seems highly unlikely; could you post the working code? In addition, without the expected `<select>` element the code will also not work, so that should be in the HTML also.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add your `<script>` tag at the end of the body.
2. Create reusable `function` from `function` in event `onchange`
3. Use `window.location.hash` to get that hash
4. Cut out the part you need
5. Set that part to `select` value
6. Call reusable `function`

```
<body>
   ....................................
   <script>
    function onChange(el) {
      document.getElementById("legend_day1").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("legend_day2").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("legend_day3").style.display = 'none';

      if (el.value === 'day1') {
        document.getElementById("legend_day1").style.display = 'block';
      } else if (el.value === 'day2') {
        document.getElementById("legend_day2").style.display = 'block';
      } else if (el.value === 'day3') {
        document.getElementById("legend_day3").style.display = 'block';
      }
    }

    let selectLayersEl = document.getElementById("selectLayers")
    let selectEl = document.querySelector("#selectLayers > select")

    selectLayersEl.addEventListener('change', function handleChange(event) {
      onChange(event.target)
    });

    let hash = window.location.hash;
    let day = hash.slice(hash.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)

    selectEl.value = day;

    onChange(selectEl)
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you, I was able to get your code working. this is saving me around 50% of extra coding.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is below, with explanatory comments in the code itself:

```js
// simple utility functions to provide aliases
// document.createElement(), allowing properties to be
// assigned to the created element at the point of creation,
// and also for both querySelector() and querySelectorAll()
// for both the Document and Element interfaces (which is
// used depends on whether a context is passed to the function,
// and whether thatn context is an Element or Document,
// the function defaults to Document).
// The querySelectorAll() (getAll) alias returns an Array
// of nodes instead of a NodeList:
const D = document,
  create = (tag, props) => Object.assign(D.createElement(tag), props),
  get = (selector, context = D) => context.querySelector(selector),
  getAll = (selector, context = D) => [...context.querySelectorAll(selector)],
  // a simple function to generate a 'hash' that ends with
  // 'day1', 'day2', or 'day3':
  generateHash = () => {
    // creating an Array, using Array.from() with an Object literal
    let numbers = Array.from({
        // which specicifies the length of the Array:
        length: 3
        // iterating over that Array using Array.prototype.map()
        // along with an arrow function, in which we take the index
        // of the array element/entry, and add 1; in order to
        // generate an Array starting at 1 instead of 0:
      }).map((_, i) => i + 1),
      // we then generate a random number in a range from 0
      // to the size of the Array:
      index = Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length);
    // and return a template-literal string which forms a
    // rtring that approximates the type of path/hash you're
    // expecting (albeit simplified):
    return `#uri/path/hash/day${numbers[index]}`;
  },
  // the function to handle the 'change' event:
  handleChange = (evt) => {
    // here we retrieve the current element to which the
    // function was bound:
    let current = evt.currentTarget,
      // retrieving the current value:
      value = current.value;

    // we use the getAll() alias of document.querySelectorAll()
    // to retrieve all <div> elements with an id attribute
    // starting with 'legend'; and we iterate over that Array
    // of nodes using Array.prototype.forEach():
    getAll('div[id^=legend]').forEach(
      // here we pass a reference to the current Node of the
      // Array of Nodes, and update its 'hidden'
      // property/attribute depending on whether the id of the
      // current node ends with the value; because we want to
      // show the element with the matching id; we first call
      // String.prototype.endsWith() to see if it ends with
      // the supplied value (if so the function returns
      // Boolean true), and we invert the result so that
      // if there's a match, the element.hidden property
      // is set to false, so that it's shown in the page:
      (el) => el.hidden = !el.id.endsWith(value)
    );
  },
  // retrieving a hash-like string:
  hashCache = generateHash();

// getting a reference to the <body> element, and prepending
// a newly-created <a> element:
get('body').prepend(create('a', {
  // setting its href to the hash we retrieved:
  href: hashCache,
  // setting its text-content to the same string
  // (we could have used a pseudo-element to do
  // this, but it felt 'tidier' doing it this way):
  textContent: hashCache
}));

// in production you should obviously use
// location.hash can be called on any Location
// whether that's document.location, window.location,
// or HTMLAnchorElement.location; in production you
// should obviously use document, or window, in place
// of the <a> element:
let fauxHash = get('a').hash;

// h ere we get the <select> element, and use
// EventTarget.addEventListener to bind the handleChange
// function (note the deliberate lack of parentheses, we're
// binding the function here and not calling it) as the
// 'change' event-handler:
get("select").addEventListener('change', handleChange);

// here we're adding an anonymous Event Listener on the
// Window, once the DOM content is loaded:
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  // finding the first <a> element in the document:
  let anchor = get('a'),
    // finding the first <select> element:
    select = get('select'),
    // retrieving the hash of the <a> element,
    // splitting it on the '/' character, and
    // retrieving last entry in that hash:
    hash = anchor.hash.split('/').pop();

  // from the <select> element we're retrieving the
  // first <option> that has a value attribute which
  // matches the retrieved last-part of the hash
  // we retrieved earlier, and then we retrieve its
  // index and update HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex
  // property to assign that <option> as the currently
  // selected <option>:
  select.selectedIndex = get(`option[value=${hash}`, select).index;

  // here we trigger the change event on the <select>
  // element, which triggers a call to the event-handler
  // function we bound above:
  select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
})
```

```html
<form name="AdditionalLayer" class="form" id="selectLayers">
  <select>
    <!-- here I've added the selected, and disabled,
         attributes to the 'label' <option> to ensure
         that if any JS fails the 'label' will be shown
         and cannot be reselected by the user: -->
    <option value="-1" selected disabled>Select Layer:</option>
    <option value="day1">Day 1</option>
    <option value="day2">Day 2</option>
    <option value="day3">Day 3</option>
  </select>
</form>


<div id="legend_day1">day 1 Legend</div>
<div id="legend_day2">day 2 Legend</div>
<div id="legend_day3">day 3 Legend</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jLrdfo29/).

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`Array.prototype.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.prepend()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend).
- [`element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
- [`element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).
- [`Event()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).
- [`HTMLAnchorElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement).
- [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement).
- [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement).
- [`Location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash).
- [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).
- [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).
- [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).
- [`String.prototype.endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 0):

I did find this that seems to work:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('day1') > -1) {
     document.getElementById("legend_day1").style.display = 'block';     
}
if (window.location.href.indexOf('day2') > -1) {
    document.getElementById("legend_day1").style.display = 'none';      
    document.getElementById("legend_day2").style.display = 'block';     
}
if (window.location.href.indexOf('day3') > -1) {
    document.getElementById("legend_day1").style.display = 'none';      
    document.getElementById("legend_day3").style.display = 'block';     
}
```